# How to get custom Push Notification value from launchOptions with swift?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push

I'm building an app with Swift that receives push notifications. I am sending custom values inside the JSON.

I am opening the app through the notification, so I know that I have to do this inside "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and read the value from "launchOptions".

How can I read those values and use them on my app.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what works for me in SWIFT 2 when your app is not launched. The code is not quite elegant because of the optional bindings. But it works.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // if launched from a tap on a notification
    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        if let userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] {
            if let action = userInfo["action"], id = userInfo["id"] {
                let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
                let _ = setTimeout(5.0, block: { () -> Void in
                    rootViewController.openNotification(action as! String, id: id as! String)
                })

            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler, The custom data is in passed on to the didReceiveRemoteNotification, which is an NSDictionary. The details that you want to retrieve is probably on the "aps" key of the userInfo.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: NSDictionary!)
{
    var notificationDetails: NSDictionary = userInfo.objectForKey("aps") as NSDictionary
}
```

When the app is not launched, you will need to get it from the application:didFinishedLaunchWithOptions,

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {

    if let launchOpts = launchOptions {
      var notificationDetails: NSDictionary = launchOpts.objectForKey(UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey) as NSDictionary
    }

    return true
}
```

EDIT: Remote Notification Fix syntax

Comment: Ok. And what do I do next? How do I get the value from "notification"?

Comment: You access the userInfo property of the UILocalNotification, which is an NSDictionary

Comment: I think you are mixing Objective-C and Swift through this code.

Comment: Yah. Sorry about that. I fixed the syntax

Comment: this syntax is not working at all. please update it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the **Oliver Zhang** response which is updated for Swift 5.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

// if launched from a tap on a notification
     if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        if let userInfo = launchOptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] {
            
        }
    }
    return true
}
```